# cert.verify() throws java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key is not a RSAPublicKey instance

Tags: java, rsa, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to check whether a certificate is self-signed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CertificateException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    // InputStream is = new URL("http://www.d-trust.net/cgi-bin/D-TRUST_Root_CA_2_2021.crt").openStream(); // ok
    InputStream is = new URL("http://www.d-trust.net/cgi-bin/D-TRUST_Root_CA_1_2017.crt").openStream(); // not ok
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(is);
    System.out.println(cert);
    System.out.println("Self signed? " + isSelfSigned(cert));
}

public static boolean isSelfSigned(X509Certificate cert) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    try
    {
        // Try to verify certificate signature with its own public key
        PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
        System.out.println("key class: " + key.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Algorithm: " + key.getAlgorithm());
        cert.verify(key, new BouncyCastleProvider());
        return true;
    }
    catch (SignatureException | InvalidKeyException ex)
    {
        // Invalid signature --> not self-signed
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get this exception in `isSelfSigned()`:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key is not a RSAPublicKey instance
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineInitVerify(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitVerify(Signature.java:1168)
    at java.security.Signature.initVerify(Signature.java:460)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:483)
    at NewClass1.isSelfSigned(NewClass1.java:46)
    at NewClass1.main(NewClass1.java:35)
```

This happens only with one of the URLs in my code, not the other one. The problematic certificate has algorithm 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10, which is RSASSA-PSS. I'm using BouncyCastle `bcmail-jdk18on` 1.72, which also uses `bcprov-jdk18on` and `bcpkix-jdk18on` as dependencies.

I'm assuming that this is a self-signed certificate, but of course I don't know for sure.

Comment: For this code to compile I need *bcprov*, otherwise I get a *BouncyCastleProvider cannot be resolved to a type* message. *bcmail-jdk18on-172.jar* is not enough. With the *bcprov-jdk18on-172.jar* the code is executed for me without problems (for both URLs).

Comment: @Topaco I'm using maven, so it also uses bcprov-jdk18on and bcpkix-jdk18on as dependencies.

Comment: As long as *bcprov-jdk18on* is used, the code seems to work with or without *bcpkix-jdk18on* or *bcmail-jdk18on*, s. online https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/BreakableVengefulBinarysearchtree#Main.java

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to run this stand-alone or on other java versions tomorrow. (I'm using an older jdk8) The class your output is displaying is different to mine, mine is `sun.security.x509.X509Key`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a java bug. I was using an older jdk8 version, and it runs fine on the current jdk8 version (Amazon Corretto 1.8.0_352). Thanks Topaco for your help.